# Estimate of line integral of O(x^n) function

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, contour-integration

Let $f$ be an analytic function in some sector in the complex plane behaving as
$$f(z)=\mathcal O(z^n)$$
for some $n$ as $z\to\infty$.
Can one prove in general that line integrals of $f$ (in this sector) behave as
$$\int_{z_0}^z f(w)dw=\mathcal O(z^{n+1})$$
?

I hope the question is posed clearly enough. Thank you all very much in advance!

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Integrals are monotone, so since $|f(z)|\le M|z^n|$ we have for a reasonable path $\gamma$ from $z_0$ to $z$:

$$\left|\int_\gamma f(z)\right|\le\int_\gamma |f(z)|\le M\int_\gamma |z^n|\le M'|z|^{n+1}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, bit why is the last inequality true?

Comment: $\ell(\gamma)\le C|z-z_0|$ and

$$\max_{w\in\gamma}|w^n|=|z|^n$$

since you're taking it as $z\to\infty$, so it's just the standard Cauchy estimate.

Comment: Ah, that's good, thanks!